# How to encode url string properly to avoid question mark (?) from being %3F in swift?

Tags: swift, url

I'm sending a request to server using `Alamofire` pod.

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "/hotel/v2")!
urlComponents.queryItems = [
     URLQueryItem(name: "page", value: page)
]
let urlString = urlComponents.url?.absoluteString
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(urlString))
```

The problem begins when I print out the `urlRequest`. It shows as : 
[image]

Then the request reach the backend and the backend returns me some error.

Comment: I think the issue is that you're calling `appendingPathComponent`, when that's actually a query component

Comment: @Alexander , appendingPathComponent is just to combine "devapi.myproject.com" and "/hotel/v2" .

Comment: I understand, but as I said, what you're appending *isn't a path component*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `url.appendingPathComponent`. You have created a `URLComponents`. Use it properly.

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: url)!
urlComponents.path = "/hotel/v2"
urlComponents.queryItems = [
     URLQueryItem(name: "page", value: page)
]
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
```

Here I am assuming that `url` is something like `"https://somedomain.com"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this - Swift 4 & 5

```
let url = URL(string: APIServant.API_DEV_URL + path)!
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
```